# PersistenceProviderImpl class incompatible with PersistenceProvider in Springboot App deployment in IBM WAS 8.5.5.12

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot, websphere

Stack-trace:

```
 error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    [3/16/18 10:14:36:981 EDT] 000000a0 SystemOut     O 2018-03-16 10:14:36.981 ERROR 9996 --- [ebContainer : 0] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf-org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfProperties': Could not bind properties to CxfProperties (prefix=cxf, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:816)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'properties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf-org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfProperties': Could not bind properties to CxfProperties (prefix=cxf, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:168)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        ... 113 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxf-org.apache.cxf.spring.boot.autoconfigure.CxfProperties': Could not bind properties to CxfProperties (prefix=cxf, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
        ... 141 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1652)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1628)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:612)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:583)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:527)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:495)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:460)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:410)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:207)
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:877)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:274)
        at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:329)
        ... 154 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Failed to load provider from META-INF/services
        at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:121)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.getProviders(Persistence.java:275)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.access$100(Persistence.java:54)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence$PersistenceUtilImpl.isLoaded(Persistence.java:291)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:47)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36)
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1643)
        ... 167 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.websphere.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl incompatible with javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
        at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:110)
        ... 174 common frames omitted
```

Maven-dependency tree:

```
INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ bpcs-integ ---
[INFO] projects:bpcs-integ:war:1.0
[INFO] +- com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api:com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.servlet:jar:1.0.10:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.7.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-starter:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-stream-starter:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-stream:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jpa-starter:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-jpa:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.1_spec:jar:1.0-alpha-1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson-starter:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-swagger-java-starter:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-swagger-java:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.swagger:swagger-core:jar:1.5.16:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:jar:1.5.16:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.swagger:swagger-parser:jar:1.0.30:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |        \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-quartz:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:1.8.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc:jar:2.6.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core:jar:2.6.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.23.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.196:compile
[INFO] +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:1.11.1:compile
[INFO] +- telus.mohltc.bpcs.gui:bpcs_gui_interfaces:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.components:geronimo-jaspi:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jaspic_1.0_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish:javax.json:jar:1.0.4:test
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0-b32:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.5.0-b42:compile
[INFO] \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
```

Detials:
App :Springboot 1.5.8.RELEASE

Server: IBM WAS 8.5.5.12

Java version : 8

So when I was trying to deploy the this spring-boot application into IBM WAS 8.5.5.12 seeing this issues. Based on the older posts I figured out that to use different JPA by changing the classLoader to PARENT-LAST approach but still seeing this issue.

Comment: I suspect that your application contains the JPA interfaces. Setting Parent last classloading would provoke this kind of error because the JPA provider in WebSphere will be using a different version of the PersistenceProvider class from Spring which will see the application version. That would result in exactly the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.